# Javascript Prop function not work in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to check a checkbox but it's not working in IE11. It works fine in Chrome. Can someone explain to me why this code doesn't work on these browsers?

```js
// 01_certify_01
$(function() {
  $("#calCarStartBtn").click(function() {
    window.location.href = './src/views/01_certify_01.php?mode=calc';
  });

  $("#histCalCarBtn").click(function() {
    window.location.href = './src/views/01_certify_01.php?mode=hist';
  });

  var textObj = $(".textarea");
  var warningObj = $(".warning-box");
  textObj.hide();
  warningObj.hide();

  $("#checkboxAgreeAll").click(function() {
    var chk = $(this).prop("checked");
    if (chk) {
      $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
      $("#certify01 label").css("background-image", "url('./../img/check_on.png'");
      warningObj.hide();
    } else {
      $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
      $("#certify01 label").css("background-image", "url('./../img/check_off.png'");
    }
  });

  $("#checkbox1").click(function() {
    checked = $(this).prop("checked");
    var l = $("label[for='checkbox1']");
    l.css("background-image", "url('./../img/check_on.png'");
    warningObj.hide();

    if (!checked) {
      $("#checkboxAgreeAll").prop("checked", checked);
      $("label[for='checkboxAgreeAll']").css("background-image", "url('./../img/check_off.png'");
      l.css("background-image", "url('./../img/check_off.png'");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). We need to see your HTML, and a clearer description of what isn't working.

Comment: Have you gone through the code to find which specific call isn't working? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: look at @T.J. Crowder answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606119/add-checked-property-to-checkbox-in-jquery) it may help

Answer (score 0):

I have checked @T.J. Crowder answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606119/add-checked-property-to-checkbox-in-jquery))  and its works in IE 11

try this for checking and unchecking a checkbox.

```
if(!($("input")[0].checked == true))
{
  $("input")[0].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
}
else
{
  $("input")[0].removeAttribute("checked", "checked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to create a small sample for testing the prop function with IE 11 browser.

Based on my testing result, prop function is checking the checkbox fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
 
  <input type="button" value="check" id="btn"> <input type="button" value="uncheck" id="btn1">
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#btn").click(function(){
 
    $( "#vehicle1" ).prop( "checked", true );
 
    $( "#vehicle2" ).prop( "checked", true );
 
  });
  
   $("#btn1").click(function(){
 
    $( "#vehicle1" ).prop( "checked", false );
 
    $( "#vehicle2" ).prop( "checked", false );
 
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

It can be possible that some other line of code cause this issue. Try to check the console to see whether there is any error message. It can give the idea about the issue.

Try to clear the cache and again try to test the issue.

I suggest you to run my sample on your machine with IE 11 to check whether it is working or not.